Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{4k+3}\binom{2k}k\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}=4^n\prod_{k=0}^n\frac{4k+1}{4k+3}$.

Prove that $$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{4k+3}\binom{2k}k\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}=4^n\prod_{k=0}^n\frac{4k+1}{4k+3}.$$

I could not come up with a solution to this problem. I know a similar problem:
$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2k}k\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}=4^n$, which I solved using generating functions. Therefore, I tried using generating functions for this problem as well, but I couldn't find a solution. How can this problem be solved?

For more context, the case you have solved works as follows, see here. Some more general formula is proved here.

A similar sum is determined using lattice paths, see here.

Please add context, showing what you have done.

We want to show the following identity between analytic functions (in a disk near zero):
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left(\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac 1{4k+3}\binom{2k}k x^k\right)
\underbrace{\left(\sum_{j\ge 0}\binom{2j}j x^j\right)}_{\displaystyle=\frac 1{\sqrt{1-4x}}}
:=
&\sum_{n\ge 0}
\left(
\sum_{\substack{k,j\ge 0\\k+j=n}}
\frac 1{4k+3}\binom{2k}k\binom{2j}j\right)
x^n
\\[3mm]
&\qquad\text{ (to show) is equal to }
\\[3mm]
&
\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(
\qquad
4^n\prod_{0\le k\le n}\frac{4k+1}{4k+3}
\qquad
\right)x^n\ .
\\[3mm]
\\
&\qquad\text{ Equivalently:}
\\
\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac 1{4k+3}\binom{2k}k x^k
=&\sqrt{1-4x}\
\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(
\ 
4^n
\prod_{0\le k\le n}\frac{4k+1}{4k+3}
\
\right)x^n\ .
\\[3mm]
\\
&\qquad\text{ Equivalently:}
\\
\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac 1{4k+3}\binom{2k}k x^{4k+3}
=&\sqrt{1-4x^4}\
\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(
\ 
4^n\prod_{0\le k\le n}\frac{4k+1}{4k+3}
\
\right)x^{4n+3}\ .
\\[3mm]
\\
&\qquad\text{ Equivalently (same value in $0$, and after $\partial_x$):}
\\
\underbrace{
x^2\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{2k}k x^{4k}}_{\displaystyle=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-4x^4}}}
=&-\frac{8x^3}{\sqrt{1-4x^4}}\
\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(
\ 
4^n\prod_{0\le k\le n}\frac{4k+1}{4k+3}
\
\right)x^{4n+3}
\\
&\ +
\sqrt{1-4x^4}\
\sum_{n\ge 0}(4n+1)\left(
\ 
4^n\prod_{0\le k< n}\frac{4k+1}{4k+3}
\
\right)x^{4n+2}
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The last relation is true. To see this we eliminate the common factor $x^2/\sqrt{1-4x^4}$. Then it is simplest to write down the first terms of the involved series to see which is the telescopic simplification pattern.
We have
$$
\begin{aligned}
1 \equiv
-8x^4
&\left[
\color{red}{\frac 13}
+\color{brown}{4\cdot\frac{1\cdot 5}{2\cdot 7}x^4}
+\color{blue}{4^2\cdot\frac{1\cdot 5\cdot 9}{2\cdot 7\cdot 11}x^8}
+\color{darkgreen}{4^3\cdot\frac{1\cdot 5\cdot 9\cdot 13}{2\cdot 7\cdot 11\cdot 15}x^{12}}
+\dots
\right]
\\
+&\left[
1
+\color{red}{4\cdot\frac{1\cdot 5}{2}x^4}
+\color{brown}{4^2\cdot\frac{1\cdot 5\cdot 9}{2\cdot 7}x^8}
+\color{blue}{4^3\cdot\frac{1\cdot 5\cdot 9\cdot 13}{2\cdot 7\cdot 11}x^{12}}
+\color{darkgreen}{4^4\cdot\frac{1\cdot 5\cdot 9\cdot 13\cdot 17}{2\cdot 7\cdot 11\cdot 15}x^{16}}
+\dots
\right]
\\
-4x^4
&\left[
\color{red}{1}
+\color{brown}{4\cdot\frac{1\cdot 5}{2}x^4}
+\color{blue}{4^2\cdot\frac{1\cdot 5\cdot 9}{2\cdot 7}x^8}
+\color{darkgreen}{4^3\cdot\frac{1\cdot 5\cdot 9\cdot 13}{2\cdot 7\cdot 11}x^{12}}
+\dots
\right]
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
For instance, for the blue terms, starting with only the first two terms:
$$
-8\cdot \color{blue}{4^2\cdot\frac{1\cdot 5\cdot 9}{2\cdot 7\cdot 11}}
+\color{blue}{4^3\cdot\frac{1\cdot 5\cdot 9\cdot 13}{2\cdot 7\cdot 11}}
=
\color{blue}{4^3\cdot\frac{1\cdot 5\cdot 9}{2\cdot 7\cdot 11}}
\cdot \underbrace{(13-2)}_{=11}
\ ,
$$
and we simplify with the factor $11$ to obtain the third term with opposite sign.
Since the last relation in the chain of equivalences is true, an identity, the relation we wanted to show is also an identity.
$\square$

Very nice answer. (+1)

 Introduction and initial binomial coefficient manipulation 
We will show that with $a,b$ positive integers that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{ak+b} {2k\choose k} {2n-2k\choose n-k}
= \frac{4^n}{b} \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{ak+b-a/2}{ak+b}.$$
We may re-write the RHS as follows:
$$\frac{4^n}{b} \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{k+b/a-1/2}{k+b/a}
= \frac{4^n}{b} {n+b/a-1/2\choose n} {n+b/a\choose n}^{-1}.$$
This gives the equivalent equality
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k+b/a} {n+b/a\choose n}
{2k\choose k} {2n-2k\choose n-k}
= \frac{a}{b} 4^n {n+b/a-1/2\choose n}.$$
Merging in the fractional term we find
$$\frac{1}{k+b/a} \prod_{q=1}^n (q+b/a)
= \prod_{q=1}^{k-1} (q+b/a) \prod_{q=k+1}^n (q+b/a)
\\ = (k-1)! {k+b/a-1\choose k-1} (n-k)! {n+b/a\choose n-k}.$$
This gives for the sum
$$\frac{a}{b} {n+b/a\choose n} {2n\choose n}
+ \sum_{k=1}^n {k+b/a-1\choose k-1} {n+b/a\choose n-k}
\frac{1}{k} {n\choose k}^{-1}
{2k\choose k} {2n-2k\choose n-k}.$$
The sum plus the term in front simplify to
$$\frac{a}{b} \sum_{k=0}^n {k+b/a-1\choose k} {n+b/a\choose n-k}
{n\choose k}^{-1}
{2k\choose k} {2n-2k\choose n-k}
\\ = \frac{a}{b} {2n\choose n} 
\sum_{k=0}^n {-b/a\choose k} {n+b/a\choose n-k} (-1)^k
{n\choose k} {2n\choose 2k}^{-1}.$$
 Finding a closed form in terms of three coefficient extractors 

Recall                     from                    MSE
4316307
the  following identity  which was  proved there:  with
$1\le k\le n$
$$\frac{1}{k} {n\choose k}^{-1}
= [v^n] \log\frac{1}{1-v} (v-1)^{n-k}.$$
We can re-write this as
$${n-1\choose k-1}^{-1} = 
n [v^n] \log\frac{1}{1-v} (v-1)^{n-k}.$$
Working with the sum without the scalar in front,
$$(2n+1) [v^{2n+1}] \log\frac{1}{1-v}
\sum_{k=0}^n {-b/a\choose k} {n+b/a\choose n-k} (-1)^k
{n\choose k} (v-1)^{2k}.$$
With   the   second   and  third   remaining   binomial
coefficient enforcing the range,
$$(2n+1) [v^{2n+1}] \log\frac{1}{1-v} [z^n] (1+z)^n
\sum_{k\ge 0} {-b/a\choose k} {n+b/a\choose n-k} (-1)^k
z^k (v-1)^{2k}
\\ = (2n+1) [v^{2n+1}] \log\frac{1}{1-v} [z^n] (1+z)^n
[w^n] (1+w)^{n+b/a}
\\ \times \sum_{k\ge 0} {-b/a\choose k} (-1)^k
z^k w^k (v-1)^{2k}
\\ = (2n+1) [v^{2n+1}] \log\frac{1}{1-v} [z^n] (1+z)^n
[w^n] (1+w)^{n+b/a}
\\ \times (1-zw(v-1)^2)^{-b/a}.$$
The contribution from $w$ is
$$\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{w^{n+1}} (1+w)^{n+b/a} (1-zw(v-1)^2)^{-b/a}.$$
Now   put   $w/(1+w)=u$   so   that   $w=u/(1-u)$   and
$dw=1/(1-u)^2\; du$ to get
$$\;\underset{u}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{u^{n+1}} \frac{1}{(1-u)^{b/a-1}}
(1-uz(v-1)^2/(1-u))^{-b/a} \frac{1}{(1-u)^2}
\\ = \;\underset{u}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{u^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-u} (1-u(1+z(v-1)^2))^{-b/a}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^n {-b/a\choose q} (-1)^q (1+z(v-1)^2)^q.$$
 Reverse expansion and subsequent simplification 
Expanding the inner powered term
$$\sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} (1+z-zv)^{q-p} z^p v^p (v-1)^p
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} z^p v^p (v-1)^p
\sum_{r=0}^{q-p} {q-p\choose r} (-1)^r z^r (v-1)^r.$$
With the extractor in $z$,
$$\sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} v^p (v-1)^p
\sum_{r=0}^{q-p} {q-p\choose r} (-1)^r {n\choose p+r} (v-1)^r.$$
and the extractor in $v$,
$$\sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} 
\sum_{r=0}^{q-p} {q-p\choose r} (-1)^r {n\choose p+r}
\frac{1}{2n+1-p} {2n-p\choose p+r}^{-1}.$$
Now observe that
$${n\choose p+r} {2n-p\choose p+r}^{-1}
= \frac{n! \times (2n-2p-r)!}{(n-p-r)! \times (2n-p)!}
= {2n-p\choose n}^{-1} {2n-2p-r\choose n-p}.$$
Substitute into the sum,
$$\sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} \frac{1}{2n+1-p} {2n-p\choose n}^{-1}
\sum_{r=0}^{q-p} {q-p\choose r} 
(-1)^r {2n-2p-r\choose n-p}.$$
With the innermost sum,
$$[z^{n-p}] (1+z)^{2n-2p} 
\sum_{r=0}^{q-p} {q-p\choose r} (-1)^r \frac{1}{(1+z)^r}
\\ = [z^{n-p}] (1+z)^{2n-2p} 
\left[1-\frac{1}{1+z}\right]^{q-p}
\\ = [z^{n-p}] (1+z)^{2n-p-q} z^{q-p}
= {2n-p-q\choose n-q}.$$
Once more observe that
$${2n-p\choose n}^{-1} {2n-p-q\choose n-q}
= \frac{n! \times (2n-p-q)!}{(2n-p)! \times (n-q)!}
= {n\choose q} {2n-p\choose q}^{-1}.$$
Re-capitulating what we have,
$$(2n+1) \sum_{q=0}^n {-b/a\choose q} (-1)^q {n\choose q}
\sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} \frac{1}{2n+1-p} {2n-p\choose q}^{-1}.$$
Apply the logarithm formula one last time,
$$\sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} [v^{2n+1-p}] \log\frac{1}{1-v} (v-1)^q
\\ = [v^{2n+1}] \log\frac{1}{1-v} (v-1)^q (v+1)^q
\\ = [v^{2n+1}] \log\frac{1}{1-v} 
\sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} (-1)^{q-p} v^{2p}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} (-1)^{q-p} \frac{1}{2n+1-2p}.$$
For the remaining sum we introduce
$$f(z) = \frac{q!}{2n+1-2z} \prod_{r=0}^q \frac{1}{z-r}.$$
We then have
$$\;\underset{z=p}{\mathrm{res}}\; f(z) =
{q\choose p} (-1)^{q-p} \frac{1}{2n+1-2p}.$$
Evaluating  with  minus  the  residue  at  $z=(2n+1)/2$
because the  residue at  infinity is zero  and residues
sum to zero we find
$$\frac{1}{2} q! \prod_{r=0}^q \frac{1}{(2n+1)/2-r}
= \frac{1}{2} q! \, 2^{q+1} 
\frac{1}{2n+1-2q} \prod_{r=0}^{q-1} \frac{1}{2n+1-2r}
\\ = \frac{1}{2} q! \, 2^{q+1}
\frac{1}{2n+1-2q} \frac{(2n+1-2q)!!}{(2n+1)!!}
\\ = \frac{1}{2} q! \, 2^{q+1}
\frac{1}{2n+1-2q} \frac{2^n n!}{(2n+1)!}
\frac{(2n+1-2q)!}{2^{n-q} (n-q)!}.$$
Multiply by $(2n+1) {2n\choose n}$
$$q! \, 2^{2q} \frac{1}{n!} \frac{(2n-2q)!}{(n-q)!}
= 2^{2q} {n\choose q}^{-1} {2n-2q\choose n-q}.$$
Substitute into  the sum  where the two  ${n\choose q}$
cancel each other,
$$\frac{a}{b} \sum_{q=0}^n {-b/a\choose q} 
(-1)^q 2^{2q} {2n-2q\choose n-q}
\\ = \frac{a}{b} \sum_{q=0}^n 
(-1)^q 2^{2q} [z^q] (1+z)^{-b/a} [z^{n-q}] \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}
\\ = \frac{a}{b} \sum_{q=0}^n 
[z^q] (1-4z)^{-b/a} [z^{n-q}] \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}
\\ = \frac{a}{b} [z^n] (1-4z)^{-b/a-1/2}
\\ = \frac{a}{b} (-1)^n 4^n {-b/a-1/2\choose n}
= \frac{a}{b} 4^n {n+b/a-1/2\choose n}.$$
This is the claim.

Whew! Quite a long journey.

Maybe the page will stay active and we will see additional proofs.

@MarkoRiedel: Impressive approach - worth an in-depth investigation. (+1)
